# How to separate Login View in Asp.net MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am new with Asp.net MVC and I have a problem with my designs. I have a dashboard based application so technically I always login separately from my dashboard, but when I migrate to MVC I found out that it has a layout and all views is rendered there.

My idea is to make the layout view as my dashboard,but if I do that the login will render there. How to solve this problem. This is what I want to happen to my website.

**Login**
[image]

separated from **layout**

**Dashboard**
[image]

The Dashboard is the layout and the content is the views except the login.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have the login view use a different layout.

In the view:

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/non-dashboard-layout.cshtml";
}
```

This layout would be different to the dashboard layout.

Comment: 1. Create a new layout in the `~/Views/Shared` folder of the project.  2. The code to specify the layout goes at the top of your Login view (e.g. `Login.cshtml`).

Answer (score 2):

You can either set the layout for login page null like this :

```
@{Layout = null;}
```

or create another layout in your Layouts folder and assign that to your login page